# Is it safe to remove files from /Users/$user/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice and DiagnosticLogs/sysdiagnose on a MBP?

Tags: macos, mac, disk-space

I am trying to clear up some space on my MBP. I've come across these  directories containing 211M of data:

```
$x-MacBook-Pro:$x’s iPhone $x$ du -sch
211M    .
211M    total
```

Most of the files in the first directory end with .ips. I am not familiar with this format and so I'm not sure what they are used for, buuuut, they're located in a log directory so I *assume* they're safe for removal, but wanted to make sure, first.

There's also a tarball located at

```
/Users/$x/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/$x’s iPhone/DiagnosticLogs/sysdiagnose
```

which is the majority of the consumption:

```
$x-MacBook-Pro:sysdiagnose $x$ ls -lah
total 384416
drwxr-xr-x  3 $x  staff   102B Oct 29 22:17 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 $x  staff   102B Oct 29 22:17 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 $x  staff   188M Oct 29 22:17 sysdiagnose_2016.10.04_09-14-47-0500.tar.gz
```

As it is a tarball, I can only assume it is also safe for removal, but once again, would like to be sure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have been informed via ##mac on Freenode that these files are safe for removal.

Thanks again!